# FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlProvider slow at design time

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have already used SqlProvider in the past. This time I am working on a large database and unfortunately it is too slow at design time.

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql

[<Literal>]
let private connectionString = "Data Source=SYDCO-WFTV-1; Initial Catalog=CMR190618; Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
[<Literal>]
let contextSchemaPath = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @".\CMR190618.schema"
[<Literal>]
let private dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER
type private dbSchema = SqlDataProvider<dbVendor, connectionString, UseOptionTypes = true, ContextSchemaPath = contextSchemaPath>
let private ctx = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
//ctx.SaveContextSchema()
```

Whenever I press dot ('.') after **ctx** or **ctx.Dbo** or **ctx.Procedures**, it takes several minutes before populating the elements lists. Using saved schema doesn't improve significantly.
Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: If this is for serious use, is there a reason why you are using SqlProvider instead of FSharp.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get SqlClient ProgrammabilityProvider work with SQLCLR stored procedures (it produces an incorrect mapping)

Comment: I don't have answer but would it be possible to use SqlClient for everything except the Stored Procedures? What if you download and check the source code to see if it is actually easy to fix SqlClient (the performance problem is likely tricky). Create issue in github, would be great if you can share the cached schema.